# How to override style of vaadin element?

Tags: css, vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin10

I have trouble with some styling vaadin elements. I need to style default **vaadin-combo-box** element.

My importing:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/vaadin-valo-theme/vaadin-combo-box.html">
```

And it looks like:

[image: When default style is imported]

My shared style html:

```
<dom-module theme-for="vaadin-combo-box">
  <template>
    <style include="vaadin-combo-box-default-theme">
        [part="input-field"] {
          padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

What did i do wrong ? And any advice ?

Comment: Your dom-module is missing an `id`. You need to have a unique identifier for each module. Otherwise, they can’t be used.

Comment: Also, you don’t need to include the default theme explicitly anymore, if you are using the latest major version, which has the Lumo theme by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you read through https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/1.-Style-Scopes already.

If you check https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/html-api/ you will noticed that the part `input-field` you have defined does not exist for the combobox. The documentation lists:

- text-field:  The text field
- clear-button:    The clear button
- toggle-button:   The toggle button

The `<vaadin-text-field>` used by the combo-box has an `input-field` part. But if you want to style that one, you will need to add a custom styling for the text-field itself.

Comment: Paul’s correct – combo box uses vaadin-text-field internally, so you should target your theme module for that. We should improve our styling documentation to show these hierarchies.